# Stepping through a generator in Python 3 (representing a chess game, for example)

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

My question is about understanding generators, not about interacting with a chess game, which I'm only using as an example.

This creates a generator that represent a chess game:

```
>>> from chess import pgn

>>> a_game = pgn.read_game(open('achessgame.pgn')) #importing game from a file
```

And then, I try to step through the game, but it returns always the 1st move:

```
>>> next(a_game.main_line())
Move.from_uci('e2e4')
>>> next(a_game.main_line())
Move.from_uci('e2e4')
```

But, then, this is how it actually steps through:

```
a = a_game.main_line()
>>> next(a)
Move.from_uci('e2e4')
>>> next(a)
Move.from_uci('e7e5')
```

Why does the `next()` in the 1st case keeps outputing the 1st move, but the generator `a` in the 2nd steps through the game? 
Both `a_game.main_line` and `a` are generators, but why don't they behave the same?

Comment: Because `.main_line()` creates a *new* iterator each time?

Comment: Related, maybe dup: [Why my generator always returns the same value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/31708002)

Comment: a_game.main_line is definitely not a generator, but a method. When you run it, it returns a generator. When you run this generator, it returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe is right. Python (and every language) cares about the identity of an object, not just its value. When you call `a_game.main_line()`, you get a new generator, with its own set of objects (`Move`s). When you assign it to a variable (`a`), you are retaining the same generator instead of making a new one, so it will continue.